# How to get exit code from Python?

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a python code. I use cmd file to execute my python code. In the cmd file, I am going to get errorlevel from my python code.

```
infile = "FeatureByte.txt"
Array = ["6J", "yB", "ss", "11"]

with open(infile, "r") as input_file:
    output_list = []
    for rec in input_file.read().splitlines():
       rec = rec[:-3]  
       FBlist = [rec[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(rec), 2)] 
       output_list.append(FBlist)
       print(output_list)

FBlist_set = set(FBlist)
Array_set = set (Array)

if Array_set & FBlist_set:
    print ("Found")
    exit(0)
else:
    print ("Not Found")
exit(1)
```

This is my cmd file :

```
set logfile=C:\Users\Log.txt
set PYTHONPATH="C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32"
set PYTHONEXE="%PYTHONPATH%\Python -B"


"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" -B C:\Users\Desktop\Pyth.py

echo %ERRORLEVEL% >> "%logfile%"
```

From these both code, I always get 1 inside my Log.txt file.

Comment: Are you sure the code is branching as you expect it to? `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` should work for what you want to do. Do you see correct `print` outputs when running the Python code?

Comment: You want `and` not `&` for multiple conditions; `&` is the bitwise AND.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa . Yes, It works n ow, the problem is when I execute my cmd file using run as administrator, it always return 1. But when I execute the cmd file directly, It return me 0 and 1. Any idea for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
if Array_set & FBlist_set:
    print ("Found")
    exit(0)
```

Change it to:

```
if Array_set and FBlist_set:
   print ("Found")
   exit(0)
else:
    print ("Not Found")
exit(1)
```

`&` that you use is bitwise operator and not the logical operator `and`. Because of which the `if` condition fails and you  get to the `else` part which returns `exit(1)` to you as status code.

Comment: I think its not the problem. It works now with my previous code. The problem is, when I execute my cmd file I run as administrator, it always return 1. But when I run the cmd file directly, It return me 1 and 0. Is there any idea about this case?

Answer (score 0):

The noticed return of 0 and 1 as commented response to roganjosh and Devanshu Misra's solution is because your If-statement is written to do so due to a indentation typo (perhaps lacking an IDE editor?).

You have:

```
if Array_set & FBlist_set:
    print ("Found")
    exit(0)
else:
    print ("Not Found")
exit(1)
```

This code always exits with "1". In some cases it exits first with "0" but followed with "1".

It should be:

```
if Array_set and FBlist_set:
    print ("Found")
    exit(0)
else:
    print ("Not Found")
    exit(1)                 # <--- this exit(1) should be inside the "else" clause.
```

No need here to point out the use of "&" instead of "and" as this was addressed earlier by roganjosh. Anyway, keep an eye on the changed color of "and". Its blue and means that it became a selection participant in the if-statement.

... but watch out for the result `FBlist = ['']` because it will trigger a false positive FBlist_set and thus exit the wrong way.

Enjoy ;-)